# Is a UITableViewCell and its outlets initialized after `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, iboutlet

Is it save to access an outlet of a custom `UITableViewCell` right after instantiating it with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`?

E.g.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    var image: UIImage?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        update()
    }        

    func update() {
        myImageView.image = image
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIView() {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellIdentifier") as! MyCell
        cell.image = UIImage(...)
        cell.update()
    }
}
```

I have used this implementation a lot but very rarely (<0.001%) I get a crash report pointing to line `myImageView.image = image`.

**UPDATE:** 
So far the crashes have been observed only for one specific implementation where 1 outlet is linked to many `UIImageView()` in custom cells because they share the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns an optional which is not safe.

Use this method instead which is safe because it returns an non-optional cell

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellIdentifier",
           forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell
```

Since the `image` property of an `UIImageView` object can be `nil` it's recommended to declare related `UIImage` properties as optional (`?`) rather than implicit unwrapped optional (`!`) without the default initializer (`()`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I will update the code. However if it returns nil for the cell then I think the crash would happen at line `cell.image = UIImage(...)` instead of `myImageView.image = image`.

Comment: My bad, the property is declared as optional, corrected the typo.